# Можно ли как-то клонировать JLabel в Java?

Tags: java, swing

В общем мне нужно что-то типа стрельбы из автомата для небольшого проекта, но я совсем недавно стал изучать Java поэтому не знаю как. По сути вся игра состоит из JLabelОВ, то и дело перемещающихся в нужные точки. Из всего осталось только пули сделать. Тут и встаёт вопрос: можно ли как-то клонировать один JLabel, после чего его клон "полетит" вперёд, а он сам останется на том же месте. Я не знаю, может какие библиотеки есть...

Comment: Можно создать собственный класс расширяющий JLabel в котором реализовать метод clone()

Answer (score 0):

Вот набросал пример

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(p,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        MyLabel l = new MyLabel();
        p.add(l);
        l.setLocation(0,0);

    JButton b = new JButton(new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MyLabel lc = l.clone();
            Point point0 = lc.getLocation();
            lc.setLocation(point0.x+20,point0.y);
            p.add(lc);
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(p);
        }
    });

    b.setText("выстрел");
    f.getContentPane().add(b,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    f.setVisible(true);
}



private class MyLabel extends JLabel{

    public MyLabel() {
        super("x");
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(15,15);
        setPreferredSize(dim);
        setMaximumSize(dim);
        setMinimumSize(dim);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    }

    @Override
    public MyLabel clone(){
        MyLabel l = new MyLabel();
        l.setText(getText());
        l.setIcon(getIcon());
        return l;
    }

}
```

Comment: Но как им пользоваться? Я его добавил в JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER, потом при нажатии мыши я пишу MyLabel.clone() и setLocation()... Но он даже не появился.

Comment: дополнил пример вставкой клона на панель по нажатию кнопки